# Excel Help: Search for Second/Third iteration to find matched status

Tags: excel, search, indexing

[Two sheets of info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB3Ch.png)

I've 2 sheets of data(but pasted in one sheet itself), in that I'm trying to find Status of each Job for a particular date based on the server name. And my formulas are working without any issues until no duplicates on the same date.

If the job runs twice / thrice on the same day then my condition fails. Now I want to add one more condition to qualify the time range.

Here is my conditions..
If the time is before 5 PM and the latest job which is near to 5PM is success then it should capture success.
And any jobs that is failed before 5 PM is a failure. And if it has Failed, Success, Failed before 5PM then it is Failed (coz the latest is failed).

Here I'm using one more formula to convert Text to Date format but I'm not converting time from that Text. Any help would be appreciated. And I'm fine to add one more column for Time aswell.

I'm using 2 formulas here..
=INDEX(I2:I8,MATCH(1,(A2=L2:L8)*(C1=J2:J8),0)) #to find status

=DATE((MID((TEXT(LEFT(K2,10),"mm/dd/yyyy")), FIND("/", (TEXT(LEFT(K2,10),"mm/dd/yyyy")), FIND("/", (TEXT(LEFT(K2,10),"mm/dd/yyyy")))+1)+1,256)),LEFT((TEXT(LEFT(K2,10),"mm/dd/yyyy")),FIND("/",(TEXT(LEFT(K2,10),"mm/dd/yyyy")))-1),(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("/"&(TEXT(LEFT(K2,10),"mm/dd/yyyy"))&REPT(" ",6),"/",REPT(",",255)),2*255,255),",","")))
#to convert text to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this using 2 helper columns:

1. Helper Column 1 (Date)
   Here I extracted the date from the field "Date & Time" with the following formula:

   =DATE(RIGHT(MID(L2;1;FIND(" ";L2)-1);4);LEFT(L2;FIND("/";L2)-1);MID(L2;FIND("/";L2)+1;FIND("/";L2;FIND("/";L2)+1)-FIND("/";L2)-1))
2. Helper Column 2 (Flag Time)
   Here I put a value to determine if the time is before 5 p.m. and which is the closer time to this hour.

   - First we have to extract the time value, so I used to formula to do it:

   --MID(L2,FIND(" ",L2)+1,LEN(L2))

   - In order to determine if the time is before 5 p.m. I used (giving a greater value if the time is after 5 p.m.):

   IF(Time<=17/24,0,10)

   - Finally I get a value related to how closer is the time to 5 p.m.

   (17/24-Time)

And the final formula is:

```
=IF(--MID(L2,FIND(" ",L2)+1,LEN(L2))<=17/24,0,10)+(17/24-(--MID(L2,FIND(" ",L2)+1,LEN(L2))))
```

With these values on the helper columns now we can achieve what you're looking for. I'm using this array formula (don't forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to works correctly):

```
=IF(SUM(($M$2:$M$8=$A2)*($J$2:$J$8=B$1))=0,"",INDEX($I$2:$I$8,MAX(IF(MIN(IF(($M$2:$M$8=$A2)*($J$2:$J$8=B$1),$K$2:$K$8,""))=($M$2:$M$8=$A2)*($J$2:$J$8=B$1)*$K$2:$K$8,ROW($I$2:$I$8)-1,""))))
```

And this is the result that we got:
[image]

[You cand find an example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16bv4Z1LQ2LJC8jvqI7w7dcadnmQMikBe/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true) (you have to download as an excel file to test it)

Comment: This is good if the month is single digit however it is not working if the month is 2 digit (10/11/12). but that is ok, I'm using my above mentioned formula to get the date. And also I've a question here, what is the flag time format here ? I see the format in decimals like 0.0746252.

Comment: I have updated the formula to extract the date and now is working right. About the time question, excel read time as a proportion of 24 hours, for example 5 p.m. (17 hours of the day) is equal to 17/24.

Comment: Not sure but the changed formula is not working. results are coming as 00-01-1900. and the flag time is coming as 0.071321.. My sheet is working fine with my formula for date but the flag time format is not understandable .

Comment: It's difficult to know without an example of your file, I just tried to guess the format of your data based on the Image you shared, but sometimes that is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from the system. I couldn't find a way to upload the screenshot here. Is there a way to send the info to you ?  And also I'm getting one more error now. I'm getting value error for this date format 27-08-2021  02:51:00. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Could you upload a sample file on google sheets? That would be really helpul in order to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Here is the link to access the excel in googlesheets.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19hlQ2SHtZG4vSo6iVeTw07xW17X7TskjlDGSEi6Yz28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I thought that your data was set as text, but is just formatted as date & time, with this is so much easier to give you an answer, please check this file (download as msExcel file in order to test it): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11D2yYjAWsvY5oJqSZXkuI4F9h9IMro12/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Thanks you Soo much for sticking on this issue and resolving my issue.. Your help solved my problem and now I can get what I want. Thanks again for your support !!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help!